# About vertex algebra, mode expansion

Tags: cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras

A vertex operator is a linear map associating every state to a operator-valued distributions (quantum field) on a algebra curve, which is also called operator-state correspondence.
Chose a local complex coordinate, we can locally expand  quantum fields as operator valued formal Laurent series, this process is called mode expansion (?), the coefficients are called Fourier coefficients.
I confuse the terminology Fourier coefficients, why people give them this name, does mode expansion relate to Fourier transformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expand a meromorphic function in a Laurent series about $z=0$ and now take $z$ on the unit circle in the complex plane, so that $z= e^{i\theta}$, then the Laurent series is a Fourier series.